# How do I calculate the total time a gauge was set on -1 in a day?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a gauge in Prometheus that has the value -1 when my service is down (my deployment has 0 pods). When the service is up, the gauge keeps the number of users logged in. I am trying to calculate the total time this gauge was -1 during a day and maybe a weekly average.

I tried to use the `timestamp()` function like this: `timestamp(my_gauge[1d] == -1)`, but I get an error. I tried other stuff, like `min_over_time()` but that also didn't work.

EDIT: If anyone has another idea on how to calculate the total time a k8s deployment was down in a day, without using my gauge, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time a service was down during the previous 24h hours using:

```
avg_over_time((my_gauge == bool 0)[1d:])
```

You need a Prometheus with subquery support (version 2.7) and you can generate the metric only on a sliding window.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with this: ```sum_over_time( (my_gauge == bool -1)[1d:] ) ```. That gives me the numer of minutes my gauge was -1 in the last day.

Answer (score 1):

I would do `count(my_gauge == bool -1)` and read the sum over time in Grafana under Total when chart is set to 1d. You can further set the `Min step`to 1d, but then Grafan will average counts, so you'll need to multiply the query by some factor of `$__interval_ms`. Factor will depend on the frequency of metric.

Comment: Instead of `count()`, it is better to use `avg()`. Then you don't have a time factor. The remaining issue is to have the metric on day boundaries which is not possible. You also have to sue subqueries